# Formula que selecciona un rango horario y muestre el turno

Tags: excel

Necesito una fórmula para marcar según la fecha y hora el tipo de turno. Los turnos serían: mañana de 6:00 a 13:59, tarde de 14:00 a 21:59 y noche de 22:00 a 5:59.
Dado que el turno de noche empieza el día anterior hasta llegar el día siguiente, ha de poner de noche también.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

La fecha te da igual, lo que interesa es la hora. Con esta fórmula, poniendo una hora en la celda A2 (por ejemplo 05:00), te devolverá el turno:

```
=SI(Y(HORA(A2)>=14;HORA(A2)<=21);"AFTERNOON";SI(Y(HORA(A2)>=6;HORA(A2)<=13);"MORNING";"NIGHT"))
```

[image: Formula turnos]

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!